# Getting date and time from a NTPUDPClient fails sometimes

Tags: date, time, timeout, udpclient

I've been working on this program using NetBeans for 6 months and I've never experienced such an issue. It has began when I added org.apache.commons library (I needed it to get time from a online server) , when I run the program ,sometimes everything goes fine and sometimes it hangs on running state creating a process in the background. Here's the Class with the main method.

```
package samplefx.ctrl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo;

public class Optilight extends Application {

    public static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException, ParseException {

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SampleFXPU");

        String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
        Date time = new Date(returnTime);

        Access access = new Access();
        String fix = "XC193283R";
        String var = access.Y();

        Date start = Date.valueOf("2016-08-23");
        Date end = Date.valueOf("2016-08-31");

        Boolean j = false;
        if (start.before(time) && time.before(end)) {
            j = true;
        }
        boolean i = false;
        if (fix.equals(var)) {
            i = true;
        }

        if (!j || !i) {

            System.exit(0);

        }

        // load main form in to VBox (Root)
        BorderPane mainPane = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/samplefx/view/Login.fxml"));
        // add main form into the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);

        //primaryStage.setTitle("Optilight 2.2.1");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        //primaryStage.setMaximized(true);    // make the main form fit to the screen
        primaryStage.show();

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            emf.close();
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);

        });

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem could be that your request to the server runs into a timeout. Try to debug your program step by step to isolate the problem.

Comment: Additionally, if you split the start method into more private methods, debugging will be easier since you can "step over" each function to see where it hangs. Your code will be more maintainable too.

Comment: Would setting a shorter or null timeout solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this, it's a server timeout issue . I added these two lines  : 
`timeClient.open();
timeClient.setSoTimeout(5000);`
after this line :
`NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();`